# Android speed BufferedReader read line and ArrayList add and get

Tags: java, android, arraylist, opengl-es-2.0, bufferedreader

I create an Obj file reader which read line by line using a buffered reader, I have to check each line if it is a vertex I add it to vertices `ArrayList` and if it is a face I create a `Face` object which `get(i)` the vertices `ArrayList` and another 2 lists "normal and UVs" then add to the faces list.
this is the code

```
public final void ctreateObject() {
    float now = System.nanoTime();  
    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {              
            if (line.startsWith("f")) {
                processFLine(line);
            } else if (line.startsWith("vn")) {
                processVNLine(line);
            } else if (line.startsWith("vt")) {
                processVTLine(line);
            } else if (line.startsWith("v")) {
                processVLine(line);
            } else if (line.startsWith("usemtl")) {
                mtlName = line.split("[ ]+", 2)[1];
            } else if (line.startsWith("mtllib")) {
                mtllib = line.split("[ ]+")[1];
            } else if (line.startsWith("g") || line.startsWith("o")) {
                if (faces.size() > 0) {
                    List<Face> theFaces = new ArrayList<Face>();
                    theFaces.addAll(faces);
                    Model model = new Model(id, theFaces, mtlName);
                    SharedData.models.add(model);
                    faces.clear();
                }
            }
            Log.i("line", line);
            ln++;
        }
        if (faces.size() > 0) {
            List<Face> theFaces = new ArrayList<Face>();
            theFaces.addAll(faces);
            Model model = new Model(id, theFaces, mtlName);
            SharedData.models.add(model);
            faces.clear();
            vertices.clear();
            normals.clear();
            uvs.clear();
        }
        inputStreamReader.close();
        bufferReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Line", String.valueOf(ln));
    Log.i("time", String.valueOf((System.nanoTime() - now) / 1000000000));
}

private void processVLine(String line) {
    String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");
    vertices.add(new float[] { Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]), Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]), Float.parseFloat(tokens[3]) });
}

private void processVNLine(String line) {
    String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");
    normals.add(new float[] { Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]), Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]), Float.parseFloat(tokens[3]) });
}

private void processVTLine(String line) {
    String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");
    uvs.add(new float[] { Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]), Float.parseFloat(tokens[2]) });
}

private void processFLine(String line) {
    String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");
    if (tokens.length == 4) {
        makeFace3(tokens);
    }
}

private void makeFace3(String[] tokens) {
    if (tokens[1].matches("[0-9]+")) {// f: v
        Face face = new Face(vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) - 1));
        if (normals.size() > 0) {
            face.setAn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) - 1));
            face.setBn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) - 1));
            face.setCn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]) - 1));
        }
        if (uvs.size() > 0) {
            face.setAuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) - 1));
            face.setBuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) - 1));
            face.setCuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]) - 1));
        }
        faces.add(face);
    }
    if (tokens[1].matches("[0-9]+/[0-9]+")) {
        Face face = new Face(vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].split("/")[0]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].split("/")[0]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].split("/")[0]) - 1));
        if (normals.size() > 0) {
            face.setAn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].split("/")[0]) - 1));
            face.setBn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].split("/")[0]) - 1));
            face.setCn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].split("/")[0]) - 1));
        }
        if (uvs.size() > 0) {
            face.setAuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].split("/")[1]) - 1));
            face.setBuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].split("/")[1]) - 1));
            face.setCuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].split("/")[1]) - 1));
        }
        faces.add(face);
    }
    if (tokens[1].matches("[0-9]+//[0-9]+")) {// f: v//vn
        Face face = new Face(vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].split("/")[0]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].split("/")[0]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].split("/")[0]) - 1));
        if (uvs.size() > 0) {
            face.setAuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].split("/")[0]) - 1));
            face.setBuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].split("/")[0]) - 1));
            face.setCuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].split("/")[0]) - 1));
        }
        if (normals.size() > 0) {
            face.setAn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].split("/")[2]) - 1));
            face.setBn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].split("/")[2]) - 1));
            face.setCn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].split("/")[2]) - 1));
        }
        faces.add(face);
    }
    if (tokens[1].matches("[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+")) {
        Face face = new Face(vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].split("/")[0]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].split("/")[0]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].split("/")[0]) - 1));
        if (uvs.size() > 0) {
            face.setAuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].split("/")[1]) - 1));
            face.setBuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].split("/")[1]) - 1));
            face.setCuv(uvs.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].split("/")[1]) - 1));
        }
        if (normals.size() > 0) {
            face.setAn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].split("/")[2]) - 1));
            face.setBn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2].split("/")[2]) - 1));
            face.setCn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3].split("/")[2]) - 1));
        }
        faces.add(face);
    }
}
```

the problem is in performance, it the file contains about 120,000 line this process takes about 90 seconds which is too long because I wanna load many models like that, if the file is more complicated and has 850,000 line the process takes about 280 seconds which is not accepted, the `BufferReader` can scan the lines very very fast but the `ArrayList` processing causes the slow, I tested the `LinkedList` but the result was terrible "5 times slower", so is there a method or another solution can I used to do this? later I iterate the faces `ArrayList` to create the buffer and pass it to `OpenGL`.

Edit
I used `Vector` with the same 120,000 lines file the result is 109 seconds (20 seconds increasing than `ArrayList`)

Comment: You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. Performance of `ArrayList` is defined in the Javadoc. Your problem is almost certainly the seven `if` conditions. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Yes I know that the problem is not in the BufferedReader, I test read the file and print each line it is really very fast, I ask how can I get a collection of Face s with these conditions faster than the arraylist or any hint to perform my code, may be I use something in wrong way

Comment: So you know the problem is not the buffered reade but you mention it in your title, your question, and your tags. Why? Have you considered cutting down your title, your question, and your tags to what is actually relevant?

Comment: I describe the issue in details so I have to mention the BufferedReader, could you please help me finding a solution? @EJP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BufferedReader` and `ArrayList` are not the problems.

Your performance problems basically come down to two issues: allocation and parsing.

**Parsing - Part I**

```
    String[] tokens = line.split("[ ]+");
```

You are tokenizing the string using a *regular expression*.  This is about the slowest way you could split the line into tokens.  You could speed this up by iterating through the string yourself and building up the tokens as you go.  This is the "low-hanging fruit", the small change that will give you the large speed-up.

```
    if (tokens[1].matches("[0-9]+")) {// f: v
```

Again, using regular expressions.  This is slowing you down.

**Parsing - Part II**

Why do you re-parse something you already parsed?

```
    Face face = new Face(vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) - 1), vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) - 1));
    if (normals.size() > 0) {
        face.setAn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]) - 1));
        face.setBn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]) - 1));
        face.setCn(normals.get(Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]) - 1));
    }
```

You are making duplicate calls to `Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]) - 1`.  You should just put the result into an `int` and use that.

**Allocation**

Look at how many times you are calling the `new` operator.  Every object allocation is going to cost you in terms of performance.  Look at every `new` operator in a loop and ask:  Is there any way I could do this all at once?  For example: each vertex is a `float[3]`.  Rather than calling `new float[3]` over and over and over, can you start with a trial value for `numVertices` and call `new float[numVertices][3]` just once?  That may not be doable in every situation, but you should look for opportunities to cut down on `new` calls.

Related to that is the use of `ArrayList`.  It's easy to use `ArrayList` to accumulate objects, but it's not very efficient.  Remember, every time the array maxes out, a new array has to be allocated and all the existing data copied into it.

That OBJ file format is not very friendly in that it dumps vertices, coordinates, vectors, etc. without giving you a count up front to use, which would have been very helpful here.

Comment: Yes, this is the perfect answer,  you saved my time thank you,, also i get some great ideas from this answer which will make great difference with me.

Comment: I followed all instructions in you great answer and I get amazing result, the same file which has 180.000 line and was loading in 90 seconds is now loaded in 7 seconds only, Thank you.